# Can I use class/function in C# file in App_Code besides the CodeFile for an asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

In an asp.net website, we can create a "CodeFile" for each .aspx file. which contains a C# partial class. And this .aspx web can activate functions like

```
protected void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

in this CodeFile for clicking a button.

I have another C# project, which has about 20 C# files. What I`m doing now is call the .exe of the project to do some processing. I was wondering is it possible that I can put the 20 C# files in the App_Code folder (or any other folder); then in the codeFile, call the functions inside all the C# files to do the processing instead using a compiled .exe file in my website?

All the 20 C# files is in namespace xx, at least they have

```
namespace xx
{
    class example1
    {
```

in every files. and I have have a "using xx" in the Codefile. The VS2012 can find the namespace, but the intellicense cannot pickup the class or functions in my C# project. So I was wondering if it`s doable or not.

Comment: Why are you calling an .exe file if you are using ASP.NET?  Just add class files within your project, it does exactly the samething, as what you are already doing.

Comment: Make sure your class and the functions of the class are public, otherwise only the class itself can call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can add as many files as you want in the App_Code folder. This folder is for that purpose only. And about Intelligence, try compiling your project and may be from the next run, It may add in the intelligence, Since Intelligence take some time to load all functions and stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable.

Alternatively, you could put them all in a Class Library (.dll) and reference that library in your website and call the classes that way.  You might need to change the classes to be public if they're not already (the example is internal because it is not explicitly declared as public).

To me, this would be preferable if the code here is likely to change, or you don't own it, or it might be reused else where.